# Tabbed content with drop down menu

Tags: jquery, tabs

Would it be possible to add extra jQuery to give these tabs an added drop-down menu?

Here's the HTML with added drop-down menu items:

```
            <div class="tabs">

                <ul class="tabs-nav">

                    <li><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tab2" >Tab 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tab3" >Tab 3</a>
                          <ul><!-- added drop-down items -->
                               <li><a href="#son-of-tab3" >drop-down 1</a></li> 
                               <li><a href="#son-of-tab3" >drop-down 2</a></li> 
                             <li><a href="#son-of-tab3" >drop-down 3</a></li> 
                            </ul>
                     </li><!-- end tab 3-->

                </ul>

                <div class="tabs-content">

                    <div id="tab1" class="content">
                        <!-- tab1 content -->
                    </div>

                    <div id="tab2" class="content">
                        <!-- tab2 content -->
                    </div>

                    <div id="tab3" class="content">
                        <!-- tab3 content -->
                    </div>

                </div> <!-- /tabs-content -->

            </div> <!-- /tabs -->
```

The jQuery that makes the tabs work but needs something extra to make the dropdown work?

```
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {

                    //add active class to the first li
                    $('.tabs-nav li:first').addClass('active');

                    //hide all content classes.
                    $('.content').hide();

                    //show only first div content
                    $('.content:first').show();

                    //add the click function
                    $('.tabs-nav li').click(function(){

                            //remove active class from previous li
                            $('.tabs-nav li').removeClass('active');

                            //add active class to the active li.
                            $(this).addClass('active');

                            //hide all content classes
                            $(".content").hide();

                            //find the href attribute of the active tab
                            var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");

                            //fade in the content of active tab
                            $(activeTab).fadeIn(1000);

                        return false;

                    });
                });
            </script>
```

I can post css if needed

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

```
.tabs li ul{
  position:absolute;
    left:0;
  display:none;
}

$(function(){
  var parentH = $('.tabs-nav li ul').parent().height();
  $('.tabs-nav li ul').css('top', parentH);
  $('.tabs-nav li').hover(function(){
    $('ul', this).show();
  }, function(){
    $('ul', this).hide();
  });
});
```

[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ohgodwhy/NdNnJ/)

Comment: Thanks Ohgodwhy, I think it works only thing now is the drop-down appears to be stuck at the top of the page? [treadmagazine](http://treadmagazine.co.uk)

Comment: @a_knife_a_fork checking now.

Comment: @a_knife_a_fork your top level LI items need a `position:relative;` applied to them so that the `position:absolute;` doesn't use the offset of the next nearest element with a position applied to it. This will give you the desired effect. soo..for you; `.tabs-nav li{ position:relative //the rest of your styles}`

Comment: Thanks, I've tried but it's causing all sorts of havoc and I don't the new jQery works... sorry any other ideas?

Comment: Also when I click on a dropdown menu item it seems to reload the index page instead of going through to a different page. everything works apart from that last bit?

Comment: @a_knife_a_fork you've got it under construction so it's hard for me to see ;/. I'm betting we need to create a relationship between the menu item and the page we want to show.

Comment: @a_knife_a_fork I'm heading to work shortly. I might not have the time to debug this now. If you don't hear from me within the next 20, I'll get you an answer within the next hour or two.